# Getting eBay Access Token (Exchanging auth token) with python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, python-requests, ebay-api

I'm trying to use [this guide](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-user-token.html) to get access token.

Here is my main file:

```
import requests

from utils import make_basic_auth_header, conf
code = '<Auth code here>'
url = "%s/identity/v1/oauth2/token" % conf('EBAY_API_PREFIX')
headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': make_basic_auth_header()
    }

data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    # 'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'state': None,
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': conf('EBAY_RUNAME')
}
r = requests.post(
    url,
    data=data,
    headers=headers,
)
```

Here's the `make_basic_auth_header()` function:

```
def make_basic_auth_header():
    auth_header_payload = '%s:%s' % (conf('EBAY_APP_ID'), conf('EBAY_CERT_ID'))
    auth_header_base64 = base64.b64encode(auth_header_payload)
    auth_header = 'Basic %s' % auth_header_base64
    return auth_header
```

But all I get in `r.json()` is:

```
{u'error_description': u'request is missing a required parameter or malformed.', u'error': u'invalid_request'}
```

I'm frustrated - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Addition: my files has python2 strings - not unicode. I've also tried switching to unicode - it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried passing the data dict as a json formatted str? E.g. after `import json` `data=json.dumps(data)`

Comment: It looks like the ebay link is a dead link now and I'm having trouble getting the oauth process to work. What is the "auth code" above meant to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry, I was stupid enough and I didn't see the tickbox on ebay.[image: here's the tickbox, after I've clicked it]

Comment: You are legend mate. Spent an hour figuring why sandbox wasa working and prod not. This should be somewhere on their documentation. Thumbs Up